# EOMonth Operator in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to pull two columns from one table using the previous month as my date range.  I feel like I'm close.  When I parse
the following code, Management Studio (SQLServer2012) tells me the command (s) completed successfully.  When I  execute the query, the response is:  Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Below is the query...

```
select  (column1), (column2)
from (table1)
WHERE (column2) IN  (SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) AS StartDate, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1) AS EndDate)
order by (column2)
```

The select dateadd clause itself successfully pulls the first and last day of the month...I'm not sure how to use the EXIST operator...tired several different things but all produced errors.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: if the exist operator actually needs to be used, and if so, how.  I've looked at a couple of different SQL tutorial sites and can't seem to write the correct syntax to make the query work.

Comment: I'm looking for a list of email addresses and dates in DATE format, ordered by date

Comment: something like this:                                      username1@domain1.com YYYY-MM-Dd
Username2@domain2.com YYYY-MM-Dd
Username1@domain2.com YYYY-MM-Dd

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
select column1, column2
from table1
where column2 >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) and
      column2 <= EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1) 
order by column2;
```

Your code has a subquery where none is necessary.

Comment: Sorry...Gordon actually provided the above...the above code, when ordered by column2 provides 4-1 through 4-29...doesn't provide data for 4-30

Answer (score 1):

Try using `BETWEEN` instead of `IN()`:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE column2 BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))
                  AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

Edit: I wanted to highlight `BETWEEN` specifically because the question made me believe there was confusion between `IN()` being a lookup from a list of values and not "between" a range of values.

`BETWEEN` itself can often be confusing and may be better understood if re-written as a clear range that includes the underlying operators:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table1
WHERE column2 >= DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2))
AND column2 <= EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1)
```

Comment: Well worth reading. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks Sean, it is a good read.  Is there a situation where the above fails that I missed though?  `EOMONTH()` returns a `DATE`, so it's the same as saying `column2 BETWEEN '20180401' AND '20180430'`.  Even with column2 being a `DATETIME` it would work, or am I mistaken?  I can't seem to fail it in testing.

Comment: I don't think there are any dates that this would not work for. But I always struggle with between because it is not totally clear. Some could make the argument that between 1 and 10 would include the numbers 2-9 and not include the ends (or bowers). But with t-sql it includes the 1, I always have to look up the documentation to remember if it includes 10 or not. As such I prefer to use >= StartDate and <= EndDate. It removes all doubt.

Comment: @SeanLange I can get down with that

Comment: Thanks Aaron...this is very close.  I don't get the end bower (thanks Sean!).  Dates run from 4-1 through 4-29...I tried removing the , -1 in the  And statement but it then ran through 5-7 (today)

Answer (score 0):

Made an adjustment to the end date statement.  Am now getting data from 4-1-2018 through 4-30-2018. Instead of <= to the last date of this last month, I used < the first day of this month Thanks!

SELECT fromname, completiontime
FROM Documents
WHERE completiontime >= DATEADD(DAY, 1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) 
AND completiontime < DATEADD(DAY, 1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
order by CompletionTime desc